# Linq doubts with DB context

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

Hi I have a question that is braking my mind for some days.
I have my SQL server Database and my C# application.
In the DB I have differemt tables, let me show you a simple ex
Tables:
Person
Relationship
City

Business Rules:
The person are from a City, so the person has IdCity
A person has a relationship with other person, and about that relationship you need to save the starting date.

In other projects I already did something like that, but in this proyect this is not working for me.

When I retrieved with LinQ the information about the person, the city is not coming, and an error appears when I try "person.city.description", for ex.
I try using Include("City") in the linq query, but it didn't work. Besides that, I don't know how to manage the circular reference to the person to person relationship.

One important thing, that I think that can be the problem, is that I rename all the tables from the DataModel, for example, the table in database is called Prd_City, so I change the Name and the Entity Set Name for City in c# project. So in the included I have to use the real table name, in other case the query fail, but if I use the real name nothing happens.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   List<Person> oPeople = (from p in context.Person.Include("Prd_City")
                           select p).ToList();
   return oPeople ;
}
```

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"It didn't work" is never a good description of your problem. But from the rest of your question I can infer that `Person` has a navigation property named "Prd_City", while you expected it to be "City". The thing is: you renamed the entities, but not the navigation properties in the entities.

My advice (for what it's worth): it seems that your work database-first. If you can, change to code-first and manually map the POCO classes to their table names, and properties to their database columns. It may be a considerable amount of work (depending on the size of your data model), but after that you will never run the risk of EF "un-renaming" your entities. Besides, the `DbContext` API is easier to use than `ObjectContext`. Currently, it's the preferred EF API.